# Definition of Cofinality Motivation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I'm working through Kunen's Set Theory.  In the chapter of cardinal arithmetic we define the cofinality of a limit ordinal as
$$\text{cf}(\gamma) = \min \{\text{type}(X): X \subseteq\gamma \wedge \sup(X) = \gamma\}.$$

The way I interpret this definition is the cofinality is the smallest unbounded subset of $\gamma$. Or as the smallest subset that "approaches" $\gamma$.   My question is why do we define it as the smallest order type of a subset?  It seems like it would be more relevant, at least to this chapter, to define it as the smallest cardinality of a subset, i.e.
$$\text{cf}(\gamma) = \min \{|X|: X \subseteq\gamma \wedge \sup(X) = \gamma\}.$$
This definition preserves the classes of regular cardinals and singular cardinals.  Are these two definitions equivalent?  Is there a reason why we prefer one over the other?  Does defining cofinality with the order type serve a broader utility than just to show which cardinals are regular and which are singular?

Comment: The definitions are equivalent: the cofinality is always a regular cardinal. And we often care about the order structure of a cofinal set.